# traduko: Die Mutter wäscht dem Kind die Haare

Tags: prepositions, possessive, dative

Is one of the two following sentences good Esperanto?

1. *La patrino lavas al la infano la harojn.*
2. *La patrino lavas la harojn al la infano.*

Note that I am not keen on the word order here, but my main concern is the phrase *al la infano*.

Background: The German sentence *Die Mutter wäscht dem Kind die Haare.* "The mother washes the child's hair" is the standard example sentence for a linguistic feature that Martin Haspelmath calls **Dative external possessor** (it really needs a typologist to come up with such a designation!). This construction is wide-spread in European languages (German, Italian, French, Spanish, ...), but absent in English and in most other languages of the world. It is one of the defining features for a *Sprachbund* called **Standard Average European** or **Charlemagne Sprachbund** centered around German and French and extendening to the South and East of Europe.

Comment: P.S. Related question on the conlang stackexchange: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-standard-average-european-is-esperanto

Comment: The construction is common in Polish, too, so it is no wonder that it made it into Esperanto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea of using *al* instead of a possessive is attested in [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/posedaj.html#i-nva):

> En iaj frazoj pri ies korpoparto, vestaĵo aŭ simile, oni kutimas uzi al-komplementon anstataŭ poseda pronomo: *Mi lavis* ***al mi*** *la manojn.* = *Mi lavis* ***miajn manojn***. *Ili disŝirus* ***al si*** *la vestojn* = *Ili disŝirus* ***siajn vestojn***.

There are examples in the [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) with both word orders:

*La faraono*:

> Konforme al la ordono de via ekscelenco, ŝi lavis la piedojn **al sia nova sinjorino** — respondis la oficisto.

*Proverbaro Esperanta*:

> Mi lavas **al mi** la manojn

*Nova testamento*:

> Sinjoro, ĉu vi lavas **al mi** la piedojn?

So I would say that yes, both 1. and 2. are fine.